# Cleaning up CallContext in TPL

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task-parallel-library, async-await, task

Depending on whether I'm using async/await based code or TPL based code, I'm getting two different behaviors regarding the clean-up of logical `CallContext`.

I can set and clear logical `CallContext` exactly as I expect if I use the following async/await code:

```
class Program
{
    static async Task DoSomething()
    {
        CallContext.LogicalSetData("hello", "world");

        await Task.Run(() =>
            Debug.WriteLine(new
            {
                Place = "Task.Run",
                Id = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId,
                Msg = CallContext.LogicalGetData("hello")
            }))
            .ContinueWith((t) =>
                CallContext.FreeNamedDataSlot("hello")
                );

        return;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DoSomething().Wait();

        Debug.WriteLine(new
        {
            Place = "Main",
            Id = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId,
            Msg = CallContext.LogicalGetData("hello")
        });

    }
}
```

The above outputs the following:

> { Place = Task.Run, Id = 9, Msg = world }
>   { Place = Main, Id = 8, Msg =  }

Notice the `Msg =` which indicates that `CallContext` on the main thread has been freed and is empty.

But when I switch to pure TPL / TAP code I can't achieve the same effect...

```
class Program
{
    static Task DoSomething()
    {
        CallContext.LogicalSetData("hello", "world");

        var result = Task.Run(() =>
            Debug.WriteLine(new
            {
                Place = "Task.Run",
                Id = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId,
                Msg = CallContext.LogicalGetData("hello")
            }))
            .ContinueWith((t) =>
                CallContext.FreeNamedDataSlot("hello")
                );

        return result;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DoSomething().Wait();

        Debug.WriteLine(new
        {
            Place = "Main",
            Id = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId,
            Msg = CallContext.LogicalGetData("hello")
        });
    }
}
```

The above outputs the following:

> { Place = Task.Run, Id = 10, Msg = world }
>   { Place = Main, Id = 9, Msg = world }

Is there anything I can do to coerce TPL to "free" the logical `CallContext` the same way as the async/await code does?

I am not interested in alternatives to `CallContext`.

I'm hoping to get the above TPL/TAP code fixed so that I can use it in projects  targeting the .net 4.0 framework.  If that is not possible in .net 4.0, I'm still curious if it can be done in .net 4.5.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In an `async` method the `CallContext` is copied on write:

> When an async method starts, it notifies its logical call context to activate copy-on-write behavior. This means the current logical call context is not actually changed, but it is marked so that if your code does call `CallContext.LogicalSetData`, the logical call context data is copied into a new current logical call context before it is changed.

From [Implicit Async Context ("AsyncLocal")](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/04/implicit-async-context-asynclocal.html)

That means that in your `async` version **the `CallContext.FreeNamedDataSlot("hello")` continuation is redundant** as even without it:

```
static async Task DoSomething()
{
    CallContext.LogicalSetData("hello", "world");

    await Task.Run(() =>
        Console.WriteLine(new
        {
            Place = "Task.Run",
            Id = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId,
            Msg = CallContext.LogicalGetData("hello")
        }));
}
```

The `CallContext` in `Main` wouldn't contain the `"hello"` slot:

> { Place = Task.Run, Id = 3, Msg = world }
>   { Place = Main, Id = 1, Msg =  }

In the TPL equivalent all code outside the `Task.Run` (which should be `Task.Factory.StartNew` as `Task.Run` was added in .Net 4.5) runs on the same thread with the **same exact `CallContext`**. If you want to clean it you need to do that on that context (and not in the continuation):

```
static Task DoSomething()
{
    CallContext.LogicalSetData("hello", "world");

    var result = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        Debug.WriteLine(new
        {
            Place = "Task.Run",
            Id = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId,
            Msg = CallContext.LogicalGetData("hello")
        }));

    CallContext.FreeNamedDataSlot("hello");
    return result;
}
```

You can even abstract a scope out of it to make sure you always clean up after yourself:

```
static Task DoSomething()
{
    using (CallContextScope.Start("hello", "world"))
    {
        return Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            Debug.WriteLine(new
            {
                Place = "Task.Run",
                Id = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId,
                Msg = CallContext.LogicalGetData("hello")
            }));
    }
}
```

Using:

```
public static class CallContextScope
{
    public static IDisposable Start(string name, object data)
    {
        CallContext.LogicalSetData(name, data);
        return new Cleaner(name);
    }

    private class Cleaner : IDisposable
    {
        private readonly string _name;
        private bool _isDisposed;

        public Cleaner(string name)
        {
            _name = name;
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            if (_isDisposed)
            {
                return;
            }

            CallContext.FreeNamedDataSlot(_name);
            _isDisposed = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: in your TPL version, is there a risk that logical CallContext will be freed before the Task.Factory.StartNew had a chance to Capture it?  I also need to be sure that all continuations (if any) from Task.Factory.StartNew do indeed have the CallContext, even if it was "freed" by the main thread.

Comment: @BrentArias you can test it with a Thread.Sleep (I did). Task.Factory.StartNew as do Task.Run capture (copy) the context and store it on the Task so you don't need to worry about it. You have more info about it here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/06/15/executioncontext-vs-synchronizationcontext.aspx

Comment: @BrentArias *"when you use Task.Run, the call to Run captures the ExecutionContext from the invoking thread, storing that ExecutionContext instance into the Task object. When the delegate provided to Task.Run is later invoked as part of that Task’s execution, it’s done so via ExecutionContext.Run using the stored context.  This is true for Task.Run, for ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem, for Delegate.BeginInvoke, for Stream.BeginRead, for DispatcherSynchronizationContext.Post, and for any other async API you can think of. "*

Comment: I would love to have your input on a [very similar ASP.NET Core `AsyncLocal` topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36511243/safety-of-asynclocal-in-asp-net-core).

Answer (score 5):

A good question. The `await` version may not work the way you may think it does here. Let's add another logging line inside `DoSomething`:

```
class Program
{
    static async Task DoSomething()
    {
        CallContext.LogicalSetData("hello", "world");

        await Task.Run(() =>
            Debug.WriteLine(new
            {
                Place = "Task.Run",
                Id = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId,
                Msg = CallContext.LogicalGetData("hello")
            }))
            .ContinueWith((t) =>
                CallContext.FreeNamedDataSlot("hello")
                );

        Debug.WriteLine(new
        {
            Place = "after await",
            Id = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId,
            Msg = CallContext.LogicalGetData("hello")
        });
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        DoSomething().Wait();

        Debug.WriteLine(new
        {
            Place = "Main",
            Id = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId,
            Msg = CallContext.LogicalGetData("hello")
        });

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
{ Place = Task.Run, Id = 10, Msg = world }
{ Place = after await, Id = 11, Msg = world }
{ Place = Main, Id = 9, Msg =  }
```

Note the `"world"` is still there after `await`, because it was there before `await`. And it is not there after `DoSomething().Wait()` because it wasn't there before it, in the first place.

Interestingly enough, the `async` version of `DoSomething` creates a copy-on-write clone of the `LogicalCallContext` for its scope, upon the first `LogicalSetData`. It does that even when there is no asynchrony inside it - try `await Task.FromResult(0)`. I presume the whole `ExecutionContext` gets cloned for the scope of the `async` method, upon the 1st write operation.

OTOH, for the non-async version there is no "logical" scope and no outer `ExecutionContext` here, so the copy-on-write clone of `ExecutionContext` becomes current for the `Main` thread (but the continuations and the `Task.Run` lambdas still get their own clones). So, you'd either need to move `CallContext.LogicalSetData("hello", "world")` inside the `Task.Run` lambda, or clone the context manually:

```
static Task DoSomething()
{
    var ec = ExecutionContext.Capture();
    Task task = null;
    ExecutionContext.Run(ec, _ =>
    {
        CallContext.LogicalSetData("hello", "world");

        var result = Task.Run(() =>
            Debug.WriteLine(new
            {
                Place = "Task.Run",
                Id = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId,
                Msg = CallContext.LogicalGetData("hello")
            }))
            .ContinueWith((t) =>
                CallContext.FreeNamedDataSlot("hello")
                );

        task = result;
    }, null);

    return task;
}
```